# Lifting adjunctions along a localisation of 2-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, type-theory, 2-categories

Let $\mathcal S$ be a base category and let $Fib_\mathcal S^{split}$ be the 2-category consisting of split fibrations, fibered functors which strictly preserve the splitting and vertical transfomations between them. Let $U:Fib_\mathcal S^{split} \to Fib_\mathcal S$ be the 2-functor into the 2-category of fibrations which forgets the splitting. This 2-functor is not a hom-cat-wise equivalence, but it is (according to Streicher - Fibered Categories - page 13) the 2-localisation of $Fib_\mathcal S^{split}$ at the class of 1-cells which become equivalences after applying $U$.

Often when one tries to define the interpretation of a type-constructor in the category $\mathcal S$ one has to solve the following problem. One has some 1-cell $F:\mathbb A\to \mathbb B$ in $Fib_\mathcal S^{split}$ and to interpret the type-constructor one needs an (right or left) adjoint to that 1-cell in $Fib_\mathcal S^{split}$. Often the categorical properties of the underlying category $\mathcal S$ will ensure that the corresponding 1-cell $U(F)$ has an adjoint in $Fib_\mathcal S$, but since $U$ is not hom-cat-wise an equivalence one can not lift that adjoint to a strict one. In consequence, one has to show in a case by case manner that one can construct a split adjoint, and this is always extremly tedious.

Since $U$ is a localisation, I wanted to ask if there are some general (model theoretic? homotopical?) methods or shorthands which one can use to show that in some cases an adjoint of $U(F)$ in $Fib_\mathcal S$ lifts to one in $Fib_\mathcal S^{split}$?

I apologize if the question is to vague to have a satisfying answer. It would take some time to write down an example, since the definitions are usually a bit involved, but I could do that if it is helpful.

Comment: I don’t really know, but could fibrations in S be something like pseudo-coalgebras for a 2-comonad on Cat/S, with split fibrations the strict algebras? Then the universal splitting of a fibration ought to be coflexible, with every Cartesian functor into it isomorphic to a strict one.

Comment: Oh, I think what’s weird here is that the right adjoint is extra, but otherwise everything follows a familiar story in 2-algebra: fibrations are pseudo-algebras for the “comma” 2-monad on Cat/S and split fibrations are strict algebras, so the free split fibration on a fibration will have every Cartesian map out iso to a split one and dually, for the cofree split fibration.

Comment: @KevinArlin Yes, I think your right. I need exactly the dual of Lack's paper. I have read somewhere that strict indexed categories are Cat-enriched comonadic above $[\mathcal S_0,Cat]$, but I do not know enoough to check that everything else also dualizes

Comment: @KevinArlin I have gotten the impression that it is in general harder to lift a model structure along a left adjoint. There are always a lot of set theoretic smallness conditions which I do not really understand, but I think they are not completely symmetric :/

Comment: It’s not clear to me that you need to worry about the comonad when the monad is also around.

Comment: @KevinArlin The coflexible objects should be exactly the fibrant objects in the injective model structure, i.e. the model structure which I get when I view $U_s$ as a left $Cat$-enriched adjoint and lift along it, right?

Comment: That's the idea, but the flexible objects will be easier to get at for the reasons you mention.